# Error on building sdk with solita on anchor-lang:0.28.0

Tags: anchor, solana-program, metaplex, cli, sdk

No matching version is found by solita for anchor-cli: 0.28.0 on https://crates.io/crates/anchor-cli/versions , which gives error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix I'm using:

in cargo.toml inside programs/name_of_your_program
change anchor-lang to 0.27.0

do NOT run `anchor build`

then run `yarn solita`, it will initialy start working but fail at the end

that will create anchor v27 binary inside
/name_of_your_program/.crates/bin

`avm use 0.28.0`

`where anchor`

copy that binary to .crates/bin/anchor to replace the 27 that solita built there

then change back cargo.toml to 0.28.0

rerun `yarn solita`

Hopefully soon anchor crate.io will get published at that whole tedious process won't be needed

Answer (score 3):

Solution posted by @zkKirol : https://discord.com/channels/848060988636921856/849844496941842432/1153277836157796383

Download the anchor-cli : 0.28.0 binary and copy paste it in `.crates` folder which solita creates then run `yarn solita` again.

You can download the binary either using `avm` or from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@coral-xyz/anchor-cli?activeTab=code

Comment: This worked great for me. I already had it in my node_modules so just had to copy it over